# MATLAB: After reshaping matrix to array, how can we know back where the value originally belongs to?

Tags: matlab

Let `z = [1 3 5 6]` and by getting all the difference between each elements:
we get:

```
bsxfun(@minus, z', z)
ans =
     0    -2    -4    -5
     2     0    -2    -3
     4     2     0    -1
     5     3     1     0
```

I now want to order these values in ascending order and remove the duplicates. So:

```
sort(reshape(bsxfun(@minus, z', z),1,16))
ans =
  Columns 1 through 13
    -5    -4    -3    -2    -2    -1     0     0     0     0     1     2     2
  Columns 14 through 16
     3     4     5


C = unique(sort(reshape(bsxfun(@minus, z', z),1,16)))
C =
    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5
```

But by looking at `-5` in `[-5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5]`, 
how can I tell where `-5` comes from. By reading myself the matrix,

```
 0    -2    -4    -5
 2     0    -2    -3
 4     2     0    -1
 5     3     1     0
```

I know it comes from `z(1) - z(4)`, i.e. row 1 column 4.

Also `2` comes from both `z(3) - z(2)` and `z(2) - z(1)`, which comes from two cases. Without reading the originally matrix itself, how can we know that the `2` in `[-5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5]` is originally in row 3 column 2 and row 2 column 1 of the original matrix?

So by looking at each element in `[-5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5]`, how do we know, for example, where `-5` comes from in the original matrix index efficiently. I want to know as I need to do operation on ,e.g.,`-5` and two indices that produce this: for example, for each difference, say -5, i do `(-5)*1*6`, as `z(1)- z(6) = -5`. But for 2, I need to do `2*(3*2+2*1)` as `z(3) - z(2) = 2`, `z(2) - z(1) = 2` which is not distinct.

Thinking hard, I think i should not reshape `bsxfun(@minus, z', z)` to array. I will also create two index array such that I can do operations like `(-5)*1*6` stated above effectively. However, this is easier said than done and I also have to take care of nondistinct sources. Or should I do the desired operations first?

Answer (score 3):

Use the third output from `unique`. And don't sort, `unique` will do that for you.

```
[sortedOutput,~,linearIndices] = unique(reshape(bsxfun(@minus, z', z),[1 16]))
```

You can reconstruct the result from `bsxfun` like so:

```
distances = reshape(sortedOutput(linearIndices),[4 4]);
```

If you want to know where a certain value appears, you write

```
targetValue = -5;
targetValueIdx = find(sortedOutput==targetValue);
linearIndexIntoDistances = find(targetValueIdx==linearIndices);
[row,col] = ind2sub([4 4],linearIndexIntoDistances);
```

Because `linearIndices` is 1 wherever the first value in `sortedOutput` appears in the original vector.

Comment: I got `row =
     1
col =
    13` for `targetValue = -5;`?

Comment: @kww: apologies, I somehow thought `z` was 4x4 array. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you save the result of `bsxfun` in an intermediate variable:

```
distances=bsxfun(@minus, z', z)
```

Then you can look for the values of `C` in distances using `find` iteratively.

```
[rows,cols]=find(C(i)==distances)
```

This will give all rows and cols if the values are repeated. You just need to then use them for your equation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to collect all row and column indices that correspond to the same value in the matrix of differences:

```
z = [1 3 5 6]; % data vector
zd = bsxfun(@minus, z.', z); % matrix of differences
[C, ~, ind] = unique(zd); % unique values and indices
[rr, cc] = ndgrid(1:numel(z)); % template for row and col indices
f = @(x){x}; % anonymous function to collect row and col indices
row = accumarray(ind, rr(:), [], f); % group row indices according to ind
col = accumarray(ind, cc(:), [], f); % same for col indices
```

For example, `C(6)` is value `0`, which appears four times in `zd`, at positions given by `row{6}` and `col{6}`:

```
>> row{6}.'
ans =
     3     2     1     4
>> col{6}.'
ans =
     3     2     1     4
```

As you see, the results are not guaranteed to be sorted. If you need to sort them in linear order:

```
rowcol = cellfun(@(r,c)sortrows([r c]), row, col, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

so now

```
>> rowcol{6}
ans =
     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
     4     4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've followed exactly but some points to consider:

1. `unique` will sort the data for you by default so you don't need to call `sort` first
2. [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) actually has three outputs and you can recover your original vector (i.e. with duplicates) using the third output so

   ```
   [C,~,ic] = unique(reshape(bsxfun(@minus, z', z),1,16))
   ```

   now you can get back to `bsxfun(@minus, z', z),1,16)` by calling

   ```
   reshape(C(ic), numel(z), numel(z))
   ```
3. You might be more interested in the second output of `unique` which tells you what index each unique value was at in your `1`-by-`16` vector. It really depends on what you're trying to do though. But with this you could get a list of row column pairs to match your unique values:

   ```
   [rows, cols] = ndgrid(1:4);
   coords = [rows(:), cols(:)];
   [C, ia] = unique(reshape(bsxfun(@minus, z', z),1,16));
   coords_pairs = coords(ia,:)
   ```

   which results in

   ```
   coords_pairs =

      1   4
      1   3
      2   4
      2   3
      3   4
      4   4
      4   3
      3   2
      4   2
      3   1
      4   1
   ```